# Rename window title in OS X with AppleScript or terminal

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to change a window title with AppleScript but I've no success.

tell application "Finder" to set name of window "oldWinName" to "newWinName"

Also tried 
    call method "setTitle:" of (window "oldWinName") with parameter {"newWinName"}

Any ideas out there?

Regards

Comment: What kind of window?

Comment: It looks like it's not possible with Applescript, "name" seems to be readonly: https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/03.html

Answer (score 2):

window of which application?

eg, for terminal.app

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set custom title of window 1 to "hello world"   
end tell
```

or, for textedit.app

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set name of window 1 to "hello world"
end tell
```

most applications would have a similar approach :)

Comment: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set name of front window to "hello world"'` doesn't really work, Terminal.app will rename itself

Comment: @localhostdotdev you can do it after "delay 1"