# How to change the window title text on Mac with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to change the window title text on my Mac with Applescript.

I followed this post [Rename window title in OS X with AppleScript or terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631769/rename-window-title-in-os-x-with-applescript-or-terminal), but it did not change the text of the Telegram app window title and gives this error: Syntax Error: A property can’t go after this identifier.

I used this script:

```
tell application "Telegram"
    set custom title of window 1 to "I want to change this"   
end tell
```

Can someone find a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram does not include even the most rudimentary AppleScript support, sorry to say.